# Mapping of key with another key value in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, web-storage

I want to know if there is any possibility of mapping between 2 different keys in `localStorage`.
For Instance :

```
Key 1: {'key1','value'}  
Key 2: {'key2','value'}
```

Is it possible to map to the existing key/value pair If the **value** of the key2 is same.
Edit: I don't want to save unnecessary repeated values to my `localStorage`.

Comment: Not sure why the close votes? It's clear that the question is about sharing a variable reference when saving in local storage.

Comment: In my project I have large content to store in localStorage. localStorage will be full atleast once a week.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you wish to do this it'll have to be in your code accessing storage. Local storage simply stores the content in a string format and therefore rich objects and reference sharing just isn't achievable, as within JSON etc. these will always be different objects that have identical properties.